# Disable the Function accidentally restarts AzureFunction

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I have a FunctionApp named A that includes 4 functions inside it. When I disabled the first function, FunctionApp accidentally restarted to update the status. This leads to the remaining 3 functions, if they are running, also being stopped. Is there any way to solve this problem?

I hope to be able to disable the first function without affecting the running of the remaining functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the Function app might restart for various reason that you can track from the Activity Logs section, After I disabled my function The Function App took update and then it Synced the Function Trigger with the latest modified time. ***This happens, Because, When you disable one Function Trigger, Application setting with :-***

***Configuration Setting:-***

```
AzureWebJobs.HttpTrigger1.Disabled:1
```

***Gets added in the Function app Configuration, Thus once any Application Setting is updated the Function app restarts or Updates by default.***

> Note- Whenever any application settings is updated, added or removed after you click on Save, The Function App restarts.

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

***Activity Logs:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

***My Function App with 4 Triggers and 1 Trigger disabled:-***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, if you restart while the 3 functions HttpTrigger1,2,3 are running, it doesn't seem very good, right?

Comment: Yes, But the App settings are added at the Function level, And its a default behaviour as outlined in this Ms doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#app-setting-considerations  App settings consideration- >Changes to function app settings require your function app to be restarted.